# can't delete item from database in django view

Tags: python, django

i created a view to delete an object through a template but it seems im missing something i cant quite put together

```
def product_delete_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj.delete()
        return redirect('../../')
    context = {
        "obj": obj
    }
    return render(request, "products/product_delete.html", context)
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from pages.views import home_view, contact_view, about_view, social_view, services_view
#from products.views import product_detail_view, product_create_view, render_intial_data
from products.views import render_intial_data, dynamic_lookup_view, product_delete_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('contact/', contact_view, name='contact'),
    path('about/', about_view, name='about'),
    path('services/', services_view, name='services'),
    path('social/', social_view, name='social'),
    #path('product/detail', product_detail_view, name='pdtDetail'),
    #path('product/create', product_create_view, name='pdtCreate')
    path('product/create', render_intial_data, name='pdtCreate'),
    path('product/<int:id>', dynamic_lookup_view, name="pdt"),
    path('product/<int:id>/delete', product_delete_view, name='pdtDelete')
]
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<form action="." method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h1>Do you want to delete the product "{{ obj.title }}"</h1>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Yes" /> <a href="../">Cancel</a></p>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

when i try to delete object is not removed from the database table [image: it redirects to the page as though the object has been deleted yet it is still existent in the database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your patterns doesn't ending with slash. Try to add ending slash to it:

```
path('product/create/', render_intial_data, name='pdtCreate'),
path('product/<int:id>/', dynamic_lookup_view, name="pdt"),
path('product/<int:id>/delete/', product_delete_view, name='pdtDelete')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `urls.py` there is something like this `product/<int:id>/delete` and you are typing `produck/4/` in your browser. use this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/4/delete` and use '`/`' at last like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/4/delete/`

Answer (score 1):

your problem seems here

```
    path('product/<int:id>/delete', product_delete_view, name='pdtDelete')
```

you had left that url without closing with `/`. just do this

```
    path('product/<int:id>/delete/', product_delete_view, name='pdtDelete')
```